# Android OpenGL queueEvent why?

Tags: android, opengl-es

What is different between this:

```
queueEvent(new Runnable(){

@Override
public void run() {
 mRenderer.method();
}});
```

And this:

```
mRenderer.method();
```

And what is better for OpenGL FPS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GLSurfaceView` creates a separate rendering thread. In OpenGL, you need a current context for making any OpenGL calls. The "current context" state is **per thread**. `GLSurfaceView` creates an OpenGL context for you, and makes it current for any of the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` overrides you implement. So as long as you make OpenGL calls in those methods, you don't have to worry about any of that, it just works like pure magic (well, it's not really magic, but hides a lot of complexity).

Based on this, you can't make OpenGL calls from the UI thread without jumping through hoops. So simply calling a method on the `Renderer` in something that is e.g. triggered by user input, and then making OpenGL calls in that method, will fail. Beyond that, even if you don't make OpenGL calls in the method, you have to worry about thread safety if the method accesses/modifies member variables of the `Renderer` that are also used by the rendering thread.

Using `queueEvent()` provides a convenient way of executing a method in the rendering thread. So you don't have to worry about thread safety of `Renderer` member variables, because all access will happen in the rendering thread.

I believe you might also be able to make OpenGL calls in that method if you submit it through `queueEvent()`. But I'm not totally sure if the OpenGL context is always current in the rendering thread, or if that's only guaranteed while the `Renderer` method overrides are called. It's much more typically to just change state in the `Renderer` in response to user input, and then use that new state in your override of `Renderer.onDrawFrame()`.

Comment: just to clarify your last point: so typically a user input triggers an event on the UI thread, then we call a `queueEvent` in the GLSurfaceView to execute some desired code on the Renderer? Just want to make sure I understand. Makes sense. Currently I'm getting the odd concurrent modification exception and think your proposed typical approach would fix it.